# Bug intellisense VB6 (Visual Basic 6) ao referenciar DLL C#

Tags: visual-basic-6, intellisense

Tenho uma `DLL` em `C#` que é utilizada em aplicações `VB6`, porém sempre que esta `DLL` é referenciada no projeto o `intellisense` fica bugado.

Vejam abaixo a diferença, na **primeira imagem** sem referência a `DLL` (`intellisense` normal), na **segunda** `intellisense` bugado (após a `DLL` ser referenciada).

**Imagem 1: `intellisense` normal:**

[image: intellisense normal]

**Imagem 2: `intellisense` BUGADO após referenciar uma `DLL` `C#`: (esta faixa azul de ponta a ponta abaixo do `f`)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma dica do porque somente esta `DLL`  causar este comportamento no `intellisense` `VB6`?

Comment: Isso acontece ao referenciar outras DLLs (*escrita em* C#)?

Comment: Não, somente uma em específico.

Comment: Qual versão do VS você usa?

Comment: VS 2012 e Visual Basic 6 SP6

Comment: Já tentou [atualizar o cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2008/09/11/refreshing-the-intellisense-cache.aspx)? se não funcionar, tente alguma [destas sugestões](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13376771/1608936), uma vai dar certo. =)

Comment: O problema é no `intellisense` do VB6, acha que resolve se fizer isso no VS 2012 e recompilar a `DLL`?

Comment: Acho que vale a tentativa. Você já tentou usar essa DLL em outros projetos?

Comment: Sim, já tentei em outros projetos, sempre buga o intellisense.